# How can I make geom_rect to color with frequency in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My problem consists of not being able to use `scale_color_gradient2` with `geom_rect`. How can i make the color of different rectangles based on frequency? I have seen the documentation, it says that color can be used in `geom_tile` but nothing about `geom_rect`. Can I in some way color the `geom_rect` based on frequency?

```
    d=data.frame(x1=c(1,3,1,5,4), x2=c(2,4,3,6,6), y1=c(1,1,4,1,3), y2=c(2,2,5,3,5), freq=c('23','2','12','55','84'), r=c(1,2,3,4,5))

ggplot() + 
      scale_x_continuous(name="x") + 
      scale_y_continuous(name="y") +
      geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, fill=freq), color="black", alpha=0.5) +
      geom_text(data=d, aes(x=x1+(x2-x1)/2, y=y1+(y2-y1)/2, label=r), size=4) +
      scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red")
```

Any method is acceptable as long as I can color in the following order: 
green - yellow - red.

Comment: 1) Start with `ggplot(data=d, aes(fill = freq)) + `, it's better to put the `data` argument in the call to `ggplot` and remove it from the rest of the plot functions. 2) You already have `fill = freq`, I fail to understand the problem. 3) Why use `scale_color_gradient2`?

Comment: Okay let me explain. I want something as this: df <- data.frame(
  x = runif(100),
  y = runif(100),
  z1 = rnorm(100),
  z2 = abs(rnorm(100))
)

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z1)) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red")

Comment: Try to reproduce the geom_rect then you would be able to see the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi. If I understand the question properly, first of all, you probably have to make sure that the “freq” column is a numeric
and not a factor or a character. Then, you should use `scale_fill_gradient2` instead
than `scale_color_gradient2`. Finally, make sure to adjust the `midpoint` argument
in the call, otherwise it will default to 0. Something like this seems to
do what you wish:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.5.1

d=data.frame(x1=c(1,3,1,5,4), x2=c(2,4,3,6,6), y1=c(1,1,4,1,3), y2=c(2,2,5,3,5),
             freq=c('23','2','12','55','84'), r=c(1,2,3,4,5))

d$freq = as.numeric(as.character(d$freq))

ggplot() + 
  scale_x_continuous(name="x") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name="y") +
  geom_rect(data=d, mapping=aes(xmin=x1, xmax=x2, ymin=y1, ymax=y2, fill=freq),
            color="black") +
  geom_text(data=d, aes(x=x1+(x2-x1)/2, y=y1+(y2-y1)/2, label=r), size=4) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "green", mid = "yellow", high = "red",
                      midpoint = 45)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is exactly what I want.